# Executing "Export Studio Documentation" from Maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mule

I am developing a build plugin for maven that will execute my application when building a project. A precursor to this is to generate mule studio documentation using the File -> Export Studio Documentation provided by the mule studio plugin. Mule ESB is open source but that doesn't seem to be the case for their Eclipse plugin. Is there anyway to access this plugin functionality automatically?

Comment: How do you usally execute such project from command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise The project currently points to a resource folder, relying on the user to manually File -> Export Studio Documentation to this folder.

Comment: No command line support ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Command line support for my project or for the eclipse plugin functionality? Of course my project can run from the command line.

Comment: That's a great idea: having to use an IDE to generate documentation is bonkers. We need a way to do it from the command line. Hopefully you'll make it happen :)

Comment: The difficulty is that the documentation generates images of the flow from the eclipse canvas, otherwise it would be easy to create a way to do this from maven/command line. I agree having an automated command line way to do to this would be a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Currently that functionality is integrated with Anypoint Studio and can't be used separately. A new documentation tool needs to be created for that.